# PRAGMA foreign key error (Python)

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

Going to paste in the entire file because I have absolutely no idea how to fix my issue;

```
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import sys

conn = sqlite3.connect('offerdatabase1.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

############################# Creating the Database Tables #############################

# Creating the 'Odds' Table

def create_odds_table():

    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Odds(OddsID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                         TeamSelection TEXT,
                         BackOdds INTEGER,
                         LayOdds INTEGER)
                         """)

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

# # # Creating the 'Value' Table # # #

def create_value_table():

    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Value(ValueID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        BackStake INTEGER,
                        LayStake INTEGER,
                        Liability INTEGER,
                        NetValue INTEGER)

                        """)

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

# Creating the 'User' Table

def create_user_table():

    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        FirstName TEXT,
                        LastName TEXT,
                        Email TEXT,
                        Date TEXT,
                        Time TEXT)
                        """)

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

# Creating the 'Offer' Table

def create_offer_table():

    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Offer(OfferID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                        OfferType TEXT,
                        OfferDesc TEXT,
                        Bookmaker TEXT,
                        Exchange TEXT,

                        OddsID INTEGER,
                        ValueID INTEGER,
                        UserID INTEGER,

                        FOREIGN KEY(OddsID) REFERENCES Odds(OddsID),
                        FOREIGN KEY(ValueID) REFERENCES Value(ValueID),
                        FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES User(UserID))""")

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

# Running the Subroutines, in order to create the database with tables previously stated.

if __name__ == "__main__":

    db_name = ('offerdatabase1.db')

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

    create_odds_table()

    create_value_table()

    create_user_table()

    create_offer_table()

############################# Inserting Data into Tables #############################

def data_entry_odds():

    print('==================== Odds and Team Selection ====================')

    TeamSelection = input('Team you selected: ')
    BackOdds = input('Back Bet Odds: ')
    LayOdds = input('Lay Bet Odds: ')

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Odds (TeamSelection, BackOdds, LayOdds) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
              (TeamSelection, BackOdds, LayOdds))

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

    conn.commit()

def data_entry_value():

    print('================ Stakes, Liability and Net Value ================')

    BackStake = input('Stake on Back Bet: ')
    LayStake = input('Stake on Lay Bet: ')
    Liability = input('Liability (applies only with exchange): ')
    NetValue = input('Net value : ')

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Value (BackStake, LayStake, Liability, NetValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (BackStake, LayStake, Liability, NetValue))

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

    conn.commit()

def data_entry_user():

    print('======================== User Information =======================')

    FirstName = input('Firstname: ')
    LastName = input('Surname: ')
    Email = input('Email Address: ')
    Date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    Time = time.strftime("%H:%M")


    c.execute("INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName, Email, Date, Time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (FirstName, LastName, Email, Date, Time))

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

    conn.commit()

def data_entry_offer():

    print('======================= Offer Information =======================')

    OfferType = input('Type of Offer: ')
    OfferDesc = input('Offer Description: ')
    Bookmaker = input('Name of Bookmaker: ')
    Exchange = input('Name of Exchange: ')

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Offer (OfferType, OfferDesc, Bookmaker, Exchange) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (OfferType, OfferDesc, Bookmaker, Exchange))

    c.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')

    conn.commit()

########################### Text Based User Interface ###########################

def rootchoice():

    userchoice = input('Would you like to track a bet? (Y - Yes, N - No) ')

    if userchoice.upper() == 'Y':
        yeschoice()

    elif userchoice.upper() == 'N':
        nochoice()

    else:
        print('*ERROR* - Please enter either \'Y\' or \'N\' (no other characters accepted)')
        rootchoice()

def yeschoice():

    data_entry_user()
    data_entry_offer()
    data_entry_odds()
    data_entry_value()

    print('Data entry complete, recorded successfully.')

    loopchoice()

def nochoice():

    print('Thank you for using James\' Betting Tracker, goodbye!')

    sys.exit()

def loopchoice():

    loopuserchoice = input('Would you like to track another bet? (Y - Yes, N - No) ')

    if loopuserchoice.upper() == 'Y':
        yeschoice()

    elif loopuserchoice.upper() == 'N':
        nochoice

    else:
        print('*ERROR* - Please enter either \'Y\' or \'N\' (no other characters accepted)')
        loopchoice()

print('Welcome to James\' Betting Tracker!')
rootchoice()
```

Excuse the annotation and ridiculous headings, I am writing this code for a school project. After reading around the subject of foreign keys within sqlite3, I stumbled across the command;

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

After reading around about it, I was told that you had to set PRAGMA foreign_keys to ON everytime a database connection was made.

I've done this, but the foreign keys still don't work with my database.

*Any help would be greatly appreciated, i'm incredibly new to the world of python and programming in general, thanks!*

Comment: Remove all the PRAGMAs except the one immediately after calling `connect()`. Then remove the database file, and try again. (And "don't work" is not a proper error description.)

Comment: I've remove every pragma apart from the one on the third line (_I presume this is the one you are referring too_) and I get the same problem. When viewing the created database via SQL database browser all foreign key fields still display **NULL**

Answer (score 0):

[Foreign key constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) are called "constraints" because they are constraints, i.e., the *constrain* the values in the database. In other words, they prevent you from inserting values that would violate the rules.

In this case, you would get an error if you tried to insert an invalid `OddsID`, `ValueID` or `UserID` number (one that does not exist in the parent table) into the `Offers` table.
But you never do that; you leave those columns empty.

It is not possible for the database to automatically insert a reference to a row in the parent table – which of those rows should it choose?

If your data model requires that all `Offers` rows have valid references to the other three tables, add NOT NULL constraints to those columns.

Comment: I've tried to add the 'NOT NULL' constraint to all relevant columns in the 'Offer' table, same issue occurs. Just throws up and error saying that the the NOT NULL constraint has failed and the execution halts.

Comment: This behaviour is the purpose of a NOT NULL constraint. And see the third paragraph of my answer.